# macOS/iOS PDFKit: create document's outline root

Tags: objective-c, ios-pdfkit, ios-pdfkit-outlines

The following example code allows to add an outline (or "bookmark" in Acrobat's terminology) to a existing **PDFDocument** `pdfDoc` with label **Page *n*** pointing to page number ***n*** where ***n*** is the passed argument `pageNum`.

```
void insertOutline( PDFDocument *pdfDoc, NSUInteger pageNum )
{
    PDFOutline      *otl,
                    *root;

    NSString        *label = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page %lu", (unsigned long)pageNum + 1];
    PDFDestination  *destination;
    PDFAction       *action;
    NSPoint         point = {FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX};
    PDFPage         *page;


    // Build the outline

    page = [pdfDoc pageAtIndex: pageNum];
    destination = [[PDFDestination alloc] initWithPage:page atPoint:point];
    action = [[PDFActionGoTo alloc] initWithDestination: destination];

    root = [pdfDoc outlineRoot];

    otl = [[PDFOutline alloc] init];

    [otl setLabel: label];
    [otl setAction: action];

    // Insert the outline

    [root insertChild: otl atIndex: pageNum];

    // Release resources

    [otl release];
    [action release];
    [destination release];
}
```

The outline created is added as child to the **root outline** at the top of the document's outline hierarchy tree.

A problem arises attempting to add an outline to a PDF that does not contain any outline yet.

In that case `root = [pdfDoc outlineRoot];` will result in `root` set to `NULL` and the code that follows obviously fail.

If I open the source document with Acrobat Pro and add manually a single outline/bookmark then the code works.

**The question is:** how can I add to the **PDFDocument** a root outline when it is missing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding TOC to PDFDocument in Swift/Cocoa using PDFOutline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51689514/adding-toc-to-pdfdocument-in-swift-cocoa-using-pdfoutline)

Comment: @Willeke despite the solution is the same my question is more specific and thus different - I think both the question and answer may be useful for other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at Apple's reference [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/pdfkit/pdfoutline/1469326-init?language=objc) `PDFDocument` class provides a method to set the outline root.

So the fix is:

```
root = [pdfDoc outlineRoot];

if( ! root )
{
    root = [[PDFOutline alloc] init];
    [pdfDoc setOutlineRoot: root];
}
```

Comment: Use Modern Objective-C please.